# Ubuntu Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a scrapy spider that will inject data into a postgres database (namely in pgAdmin4), and this works perfectly well on my imac with VSC. However, when I run on an Ubuntu server created by the AWS instance

```
ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-jammy-22.04-amd64-server-20220609
```

I get the following error:

```
2022-07-29 11:49:44 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3280, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1660, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
  File "/home/ubuntu/path/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 103, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I have installed:

```
sqlalchemy
psycopg2
pyodbc
```

which are necessary to run my script, what could be causing this issue?

My database connection:

```
DATABASE = {
    "user": "usr",
    "passw": "",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": '5432',
    "database": "scrape",
    'table':'cdp_env',
    'if_exists':'append',
    'drivername':'postgresql'
}
```

pipeline.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, String
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import logging
from itemadapter import is_item
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class DataframeSQLPipelineInject:

    def __init__(self, user, passw, host, port, database, table, if_exists, drivername):
        self._user = user
        self._passw = passw
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._database = database
        self.table = table
        self.if_exists = if_exists
        self.drivername = drivername
 
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            user = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['user'],
            passw = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['passw'],
            host = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['host'],
            port = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['port'],
            database = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['database'],
            table = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['table'],
            if_exists = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['if_exists'],
            drivername = crawler.settings.get('DATABASE')['drivername']
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider): 
        self.engine = create_engine(
            f'{self.drivername}://' + #change this to your required server
            self._user + ':' + 
            self._passw + '@' + 
            self._host + ':' + 
            str(self._port) + '/' + 
            self._database  ,#+f'?driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server' , #change this to your required driver
            echo=False,
            #connect_args={"timeout":30},
                            pool_pre_ping=True)

        self.conn = self.engine.connect()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.conn.close()

    def process_item(self,item, spider):
        if is_item(item):
            table_df = pd.DataFrame([ItemAdapter(item).asdict()]).drop_duplicates()
            print(table_df.dtypes)
            table_df.to_sql(self.table, con=self.engine,method='multi', chunksize=2000, index=False, if_exists = self.if_exists)
        else:
            logger.error(f'You need a dict for item, you have type: {type(item)}')
```

Comment: Did you install the postgresql server? `apt install postgresql-14` If yes could be that it only is accepting local unix domain socket connections not IP. If you do not specify a host most clients will use the local unix domain socket connection.

Comment: @Eelke It is installed, so what is the best solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Eelke Ah so does this mean I can only connect to the databases within my Ubuntu server, and not those on my imac?

Comment: To access postgresql from outside you need to change the `listen_addresses` line in the `postgresql.conf` and restart postgresql. Also make sure to allow traffic in your AWS security group.

Comment: @Eelke What do I change the address line to?

Comment: Well, you told it to connect to localhost, so that it what it tries to do.  Localhost here means local to itself, not local to your keyboard--it probably doesn't even know where that is.

Comment: @jjanes I have changed the `listen_addresses` to `'*'`, this seems to have changed the error as all I get now is - `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`, it is as you say, it likely still thinks I am connecting to a server in the VM rather than outside. I have updated to allow traffic via IAP and TCP, still not working.